# Run threadpool on multiple spark nodes?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyspark, parallel-processing, databricks

I've run a dual multiprocessing and multithreading solution in python before using the *multiprocessing* and *concurrent futures* python modules. However, since the multiprocessing module only runs on the driver node in spark, I have to instead use sc.parallelize to distribute workload to the worker nodes. I'm having a bit of trouble and would appreciate input on troubleshooting (code below). Here, I'm just trying to split a list of 100 values across 10 worker nodes and implement threading on each of those worker nodes.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import time

def multithread(task, l):
   with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
      results = list(executor.map(task, l))
   return results

def square(x):
   time.sleep(1)
   return x**2

def partition(l, n):
   # this function just partitions an input list into 'n' chunks
   for i in range(0, len(l), n):
      yield l[i:i +n]

num = list(range(100))
workers = 10
chunks = list(partition(num, workers))
rdd = sc.parallelize(chunks, numSlices=workers)
results = rdd.map(lambda x: multithread(x)).collect()
```

UPDATE:
In addition to the solution Ahmad has kindly provided, if you'd like to make the 'workers' variable dynamic, please remember not to os.cpu_count(), instead you'll need to grab this with a spark getConf() method. Also, recommend passing this to the ThreadPoolExecutor() method (ie. 'max_workers')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `multithread` func return list of results, you will not need to wrap it with `list()`. Modify the line `results = list(executor.map(task, l))` in the `multithread` function to `results = executor.map(task, l)`
And to get a single list of results, you can use the `flatMap()` func instead of `map()`. Update the line to:

```
results = rdd.flatMap(lambda x: multithread(square, x)).collect()
```

The code snippet does not have a `import time` for importing the module. Did you forget it or it is just not included in the Question?

Comment: Hey Ahmad, thanks for the response, will test it out now. I did forget to import time, will update the question.

Comment: Thanks so much Ahmad, runtime is expected!